# Exact sequences of sheaves

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-topology, sheaf-cohomology

I don't understand something : in the notes by Justin Campell "[Some examples of the Riemann-Hilbert correspondence](http://www.math.harvard.edu/~campbell/riemannhilbert.pdf)", it is stated that there is an exact sequence $$ 0 \to \delta_{\infty} \to j_!IC_{\Bbb A^1} \to IC_{\Bbb P^1}\to 0$$ where $\Bbb P^1$ is stratified as $\Bbb A^1 \sqcup \{\infty\}$ and $\delta_{\infty} $ is the skyscraper sheaf with constant stalk $\Bbb Q$.

However, taking the stalk at infinity gives $0 \to \Bbb Q \to 0 \to \Bbb Q \to 0 $ which is clearly a contradiction. As far as I understand, that this sequence was obtained by taking the Verdier dual of the sequence $$  0 \to IC_{\Bbb P^1}  \to j_*IC_{\Bbb A^1} \to \delta_{\infty} \to 0 $$ which seems plausible but where is my mistake ?

Comment: I think the author meant exact sequence of perverse sheaves.

Comment: @Roland : I see, so is there a "concrete" description of what is an exact sequence of perverse sheaves ? Is there a way I can think of it in term of classical exact sequence of sheaves ? I find it really confusing that perverse epimorphism does not induce surjective map on stalks.

Comment: Think in term of derived category. For a sequence $0\to A\to B\to C\to 0$ in a triangulated category $\mathcal{T}$ to be exact for a $t$-structure, it is enough that they all lie in the heart and that $A\to B\to C\to A[1]$ is distinguished (Just take the long exact sequence of cohomology). I'm not sure about the converse though. But here, you have the triangle $\delta_{\infty}\to j_! IC_{\mathbb{A}^1}\to IC_{\mathbb{P}^1}\to\delta_{\infty}[1]$ (which is just a rotation of a triangle of sheaves), and they all are perverse sheaves. So this is an exact sequence of perverse sheaves.

Comment: But yes, the stalk functor is not exact in the category of perverse sheaves.

Comment: @Roland : thanks a lot, your explanations are wonderful as always !

Comment: @Roland Please consider making your comments into an answer.